# While copying text, why more than just the highlighted text is copied?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is a very minor thing but very annoying.

I am using Adobe Illustrator CC (Windows 7 station) to create cosmetic labels. They have, of course, a lot of copy. The copy is set on area type boxes. They are not linked. They are all isolated boxes.

Sometimes I need to copy and paste some portion of the text from one box to another. I do this the most basic way: I highlight a section of the text (a word), copy it (Ctr-C) and paste it in a different box (Ctr-V).

Most of the time (with very few exceptions that I have not been able to replicate) I find that not only the word I highlighted gets copied, but the text from ALL the area types. The text I highlighted gets copied as well and added, at the end of the FULL text. The same thing happens if I copy the text and paste it on a word editors (Notepad).

For example, I have this label:

[image]

Suppose I highlight the word "NEED" on the second area type box and copy it (Ctr-C). Then I open a Notepad (or draw another text area, or use any other word editing application) and paste the copied text (Ctr-V). This is what I get.

> Abc Defghlk sdsdsdsd dsfsdf sdfsdf fderereLOREM IPSUMSOME TEXT I NEED
>   SOMEWHERE ELSE MORE LOREM IPSUMNEED

Notice the word NEED at the end, repeated.

So I have learnt to live with this: copy, paste, delete the text I don't need and keep the last portion. But it is very annoying. Anyone knows what is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: I don't have a reason, but I do know that Adobe uses its own clipboard (or extends the clipboard in some manner) and that Adobe products don't honor the *other* copy/cut/paste system keys aka shift+insert; shift+delete; ctrl+insert

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me - I'd suggest taking it to the Adobe forums. I avoid CC because it seems to be always full of bugs. I have had odd copy/paste bugs in Illustrator in the past that have been cured with regular updates.

Answer (score 1):

That should not be happening. Try (in order of likelihood):

- [Resetting preferences](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-630ca.html#WS3DD3AF61-E31D-4415-A601-545A49CF16B1a) to clear out any corruption that may have crept in, and see if that doesn't clear the problem.
- `Save As` with a different filename, then open the copy and see if that has the same issue.
- Change the fonts to something very ordinary, such as Myriad Pro, in case some oddball bug in a font is getting in the way.
- Uninstall and reinstall Illustrator.

If none of these make the issue go away, file a bug report with Adobe. The Illustrator team are very attentive to bug reports.

Comment: thanks! +1 for the helpful tips (particularly the one about the preferences), but I will wait to see if somebody can pinpoint the problem before I assign the answer : )